# merge rest arguments into a new object and return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have a function with an undefined amount of argument that I want to pass along as data and merge into a new object.

Arguments can be of type object, array or integer.

the result should be an object e.g.

```
{
  arg1: obj,
  arg3: [obj,obj,obj]
  arg4: 1234
}
```

I was first hoping something like this, but the ...artRest is an array of course.

```
function foo(arg1, arg2, ...argRest) {
   return {
     arg1,
     arg2,
     ...artRest
   }
}
```

Comment: But what names should the keys have? `"arg" + n` ? And why all that?

Comment: If your going to destructure an object, then you need to say so.. `function foo({arg1, arg2, ...argRest})`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this using [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
function foo(...arguments) {
  return arguments.reduce((r,a,i) => (r[`arg${i+1}`] = a, r), {})
}

const argumentsToObject = foo(1, 2, [1, 2, 3], "name", {a: 10,b: 20})

console.log(argumentsToObject)
```

If you're not too particular about `arg` prefix, then you could simply do:

```js
function foo(...arguments) {
  return {...arguments}
}

const argumentsToObject = foo(1, 2, [1, 2, 3], "name", {a: 10,b: 20})

console.log(argumentsToObject)
```